# What is "the drop" in music?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This word appear in [the comment of a video of Bach in YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JQm5aSjX6g&lc=z12kjpsgmpiefvpjv04cifxikuzkvxmhgkk0k):

> A: Which minute is the drop?
>   B: When he and Mozart have the rap battle

Clearly this is a joke, but I don't understand the meaning of *the drop*. I have looked up in [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/drop), but all the meaning only point to the drop of liquid, or the action of dropping. I have also looked at the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=drop), but the meaning of the noun of *drop* is an expensive car, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Side note: it's a joke, but it's not a _pun_.

Comment: [Have you already tried Google?](http://tinyurl.com/psb5d4j "Have you tried Google?")

Comment: As a tidbit, that person may be referring to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6Au0xCg3PI) when he mentions that "he" (which I assume is Skrillex, famous EDM / Dubstep artist) and Mozart have the aforementioned rap battle. In that particular song you can see  and hear when "the drop" happens (at 1:06).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"**The drop**" is a term specific to electronic music cultures such as dance or dubstep. It indicates a point in the song where the rhythm and pace change dramatically in order to enhance the energy of the song.

The question here is posed jokingly, as it is one that is often asked in the YouTube comments of relevant videos by those wanting to skip past the boring section and get to the exciting part.

Further reading (with some examples):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_%28music%29

Comment: Oh, I thought it meant that dubstep "music" was so awful that one was compelled to _drop_ it in the bin. Perhaps I've turned into my parents and everything new is just noise nowadays lol.

Comment: You'd not be far off impo. Unfortunately, the wider meaning is not that one!

Comment: @Joe Dark It is indeed noise by design. Its intended to sound frenetic and chaotic- and very noisy.

Comment: [Better example (that Wikipedia bot doesn't like).](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCawU6BE8P8)

Comment: Hah! Yes this is the perfect illustration I think :D

Comment: In the better example, what is it called when the music come back?

Comment: @Ooker I believe the term is _bliss_

Comment: I want to make things clear. There is two changes in the music of the better example. One is when the music stops and the DJ pretends to have a strike. The second is when he press the *BASS* button and the music changes to another theme. Exactly which one is the drop?

Comment: That video pokes fun of electronic dance music. In a typical electronic dance track, the song will have about a minute of *buildup* in which the music gradually gains energy. Most of that video is an exaggeratedly long buildup, making fun of many of the tropes used in dance music. This part of the video includes the DJ pretending to have a stroke. When he finally presses the "BASS" button, that's the drop.

Comment: So the base "drop" here means for the moments when the base intensely kicks in. Correct? I initially thought the word "drop" would mean something like "descending", "lowering" which seemed to be mistaken.

Comment: @夏期劇場 Yeah it's a bit confusing. I'm not expert enough to explain the etymology of the word, but I always picture it as if something was "dropped" on my head. In the same way, when the bass kicks in, it is being "dropped" suddenly onto everyone in the room and they react by dancing.

Answer (score 10):

"The drop" is an expression coined to describe the moment or moments in songs (chiefly in electronic music genres such as house/dubstep) where the music is focussed on the build-up to a crescendo of intense sound, usually featuring quite a lot of bass. It is normally the heaviest part of a track, and certainly the part where people on a dancefloor would dance/move the most in reaction to it. The phrase "the drop" led to "[drop the bass](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/drop-the-bass)" referring to musicians/DJs who include a "drop" in their tracks.

[Here is an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVF_x6euKUE) of a build up to a drop (1:26) and the drop itself (1:43).

Comment: This reminds me to [Contact](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JI5noh4OyXc) by Daft Punk (I'm addicted to it). When the machine turn off, is it called the drop?

Comment: @ooker it is not the gap, it is when the bass drops in after the gap

Comment: For those less familiar with dubstep, "The bass" refers to the extra-noisy part :D

Comment: @JamesRyan can you tell me when is the gap, and when is the drop?

Answer (score 0):

For the most part everyone that has described the word 'drop' in music is pretty much right on  Target. You're missing one area where drop comes in to play within any type of music... For example the band Queen has a song titled fat bottom girls   There comes a point within the 1st 90 seconds of this song where the music and vocals stop for a good 2 to 3 seconds... They go right back  To the same spot where they left off. This is a drop..!!!